# Report using .rdlc in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application of accounting system. I need to develop reports through .rdlc files but when I am going to start with report wizard. Then the error arising. I have attached a print screen of error. Please check it and give answer. 
[image]

Comment: Do you have AjaxControlToolkit installed and referenced? BTW you could just copy the message (Ctrl+C when you see the messgebox) and paste its text here.

Answer (score 0):

Please download AjaxControlTookkit from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/90063 and install. This should solve your problem.